# Arreglos multidimensionales en C

Tags: array, c

Estoy viendo arrays multidimensionales en C , y se me está complicando entender un poco este tema, ya que no he encontrado mucha información al respecto.

Tengo este planteo:

> Un empresa tiene 3 sucursales, y cada sucursal tiene 5 vendedores. El usuario deberá cargar las ventas de cada vendedor y el algoritmo deberá mostrar los totales por cada sucursal (para todos sus vendedores, para ello utilice otro arreglo de 3 elementos en donde sumar las ventas de todos los vendedores de cada sucursal). Por último, muestre el total general de ventas (utilice una variable como acumulador).

No me estoy dando cuenta de cómo agregar este último vector que sumaría todo.

Comparto mi código hecho hasta el momento que pertenecía a un punto anterior del problema:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define SUCU 3
#define VENDEDOR 5

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    
    int venta[SUCU][VENDEDOR],i,j;

    
    for(i = 0;i < SUCU;i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < VENDEDOR; j++){
            printf("\nIngrese las ventas del vendedor %d",j+1);
            printf(" de la Sucursal %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&venta[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i < SUCU ; i++){
        printf("\nSucursal %d: \t venta por vendedores:\t", (i+1));
        for(j = 0 ; j<VENDEDOR ; j++){
            printf("%d\t",venta[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;       
}
```

Mi intención es saber, cómo agregar el vector que sumaría las ventas de todos los vendedores de cada sucursal y mostrarlos.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres sumar todas las ventas de una sucursal, pues súmalo todo:

```
int ventas_por_sucursal[SUCU] = {};

for (int sucursal = 0; sucursal != SUCU; ++sucursal)
{
    for (int vendedor = 0; vendedor != VENDEDOR; ++vendedor)
        ventas_por_sucursal[sucursal] += venta[sucursal][vendedor];
}
```

Comment: excelente, me he hecho un lio en la cabeza, a penas voy entendiendo los arreglos y se me truncó el cerebro, ja!
Eternamente agradecido.